# Remove Folder from ZIP file created by Power Shell Community Extensions

Tags: powershell

All,

I am using Power Shell Community Extensions for PSv1 and the ZIP file is being created correctly. However, I only want the images in the ZIP file and I want to remove the folder from the ZIP file.

I have the folder called newpictures that is zipped up. I then use the -flattenpaths option in the Power Shell Community Extensions to put all the images in the base path, but the folder remains.

I have been searching online for a solution. I am not sure if I have this right, so can someone look over this code and let me know if this is correct before I proceed?

```
if (test-path $PSCXInstallDir) {
    write-zip -path "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::$TestSite" -outputpath "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::$ZipFileCreationDir\$ZipFileName" -noclobber -quiet -flattenpaths -level 9

    start-sleep -seconds 30

    if (test-path $ZipFileCreationDir\$ZipFileName) {
        $ShellApp = new-object -com shell.application
        $TheZipFile = $ShellApp.namespace("$ZipFileCreationDir\$ZipFileName")
        $TheZipFile.items() | where-object {$_.name -eq $FolderToCompress} | remove-item $FolderToCompress            
    }
}
```

The variables are:

```
$PSCXInstallDir = "C:\Program Files\PowerShell Community Extensions"
$TestSite = "\\10.0.100.3\www2.varietydistributors.com\catalog\newpictures"
$ZipFileCreationDir = "\\10.0.100.3\www2.varietydistributors.com\catalog"
$ZipFileName = "vdi-test.zip"
$FolderToCompress = "newpictures"
```

Thanks in advance for any feedback. In short, I just want to remove the single folder within the ZIP file.

Answer (score 0):

`Remove-Item` won't work on items inside the zip file. You need to [move](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20276205/1630171) the objects you want to delete outside the zip file before you can delete them:

```
$ShellApp = New-Object -COM 'Shell.Application'
$TheZipFile = $ShellApp.NameSpace("$ZipFileCreationDir\$ZipFileName")
$TheZipFile.Items() | ? { $_.Name -eq $FolderToCompress } | % {
  $ShellApp.NameSpace($env:TEMP).MoveHere($_)
  Remove-Item (Join-Path $env:TEMP $_.Name)
}
```

Note that `Items()` doesn't recurse into nested folders, it only enumerates the files and folders of the current namespace. If you need to process contents of nested folders you need to specify the nested path:

```
$NestedFolder = $ShellApp.NameSpace('C:\path\to\your.zip\nested\folder')
```

or [recurse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21098569/1630171) with something like this:

```
function RecurseIntoZip($fldr) {
  $fldr.Items() | ? { $_.Name -eq $FolderToCompress } | % {
    $_.Name
  }
  $fldr.Items() | ? { $_.Type -eq 'File folder' } | % {
    RecurseIntoZip $_.GetFolder
  }
}

RecurseIntoZip $TheZipFile
```

Comment: So, when you move the ZIP file contents to the temp folder and remove the folder, do you then have to put the files back into the ZIP file afterward or is this done automatically? There is no nesting in the ZIP file because the -flattenpaths switch in Power Shell Community Extensions for the write-zip function removes the nesting. I have also been trying to figure out if I can do the write-zip in Power Shell Community Extensions and eliminate the folder altogether. I have not found anything on this yet.

Comment: I just re-read your post and if I understand correctly (noob), you are only moving the folder outside the ZIP file and deleting it, but the other content is staying within?

Comment: @user3013729 Correct.

Comment: I am trying out your code and I am told that the folder already contains a folder named $FolderToCompress (newpictures) and it is asking me if I want to move or copy the folder (yes, yes to all, no, cancel). When looking in the temp directory ($env:TEMP), I dont see this folder at all?

Comment: @user3013729 How are you looking? What output does `cd $env:TEMP; Get-Item newpictures` produce?

Comment: PS C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator.VDICORP\Desktop> cd $env:TEMP; Get-Item newpictures
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator.VDICORP\Local Settings\Temp\1
Get-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator.VDICORP\Local Settings\Temp\1\newpictures' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:23
+ cd $env:TEMP; Get-Item <<<<  newpictures
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Documents an...p\1\newpictures:String) [Get-Item], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetItemCommand

Comment: I am going to attempt to install PS3 from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34595 the server I have right now is 2003, so I am not sure if it will install, but going to try anyway.

Comment: PowerShell v3 is not available for Server 2003, but PowerShell v2 is.

Comment: This code is not working for me. If I comment out the Remove-Item line, I can see that the folder is being copied from the ZIP archive to the $env:TEMP directory. The folder within the ZIP archive is still there. It is not removing the folder. The file is not locked and I can remove the folder manually.

Comment: I checked what version I am using for Power Shell and it said v3; however, my ISE is v1. I am looking for ISE3 right now. Also, with the script, doesn't it have to be a .ps3 instead of .ps1 to reflect the version of Power Shell being used?