# Trying to extract files from zip powershell excluding .inf

Tags: powershell, zip

[Trying to extract just .sql files from zip powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21096778/trying-to-extract-just-sql-files-from-zip-powershell)

Referring to the above link, a powershell script was made to extract only .sql files.

Is there a way to reverse this, so it extracts everything from the Zip file apart from .Inf files.

Any help will be greatly appreciated, as my powershell skills are next to none.

```
$shell = New-Object -COM 'Shell.Application'

$zipfile     = 'C:\Powershell\From here\1-5'
$destination = 'C:\Powershell\To Here'
$zip = $shell.NameSpace($zipfile) 

$zip.Items() | ? { $_.Path -notlike '*.inf' } | % {
  $shell.NameSpace($destination).CopyHere($_)
}
```

Comment: What is the full file name? `$zipfile` does not appear to path to a valid zip file.

Comment: They way it is set at the moment it is in a normal folder in called 'Powershell' in C: then in an other normal folder called 'From Here'Then within that there are three zip folders called '1-5', '6-10' & '11-15'. Then within each one of them, there is another 5 zip folders labelled 1-15 accordingly. aswell as 2 .inf files. Within each of the final zip folders there is a text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be helpful if you posted your code but in general you could use an operator like `-notlike` or `-notmatch` to achieve what you want to do.

Comment: The code is now above. it throws back an error stating  'You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.'

Comment: @user3586898 well the path to your zip file is missing the extension, thats why $zip is null, the path should be something like `$zipfile = "C:\powershell\from here\1-5.zip"`

Comment: ok that worked like that. Thankyou. I don't suppose you know how to make it so it scans all of a directory rather than specifying the folder?

Comment: @user3586898 if it works please accept the answer, for your second question i suggest you check out the `Get-Childitem` cmdlet (Here is an article that explains the basic usage: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176841.aspx)